# Powershell cmdlet ignores an array parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to use a PowerShell cmdlet to create a resource in Azure cloud:

```
$Gateway = New-AzApplicationGateway `
    -Name $GatewayName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -Location $Location `
    -Sku $GatewaySku `
    -GatewayIPConfigurations $GatewayIPconfig `
    -FrontendIPConfigurations $FrontendIpConfig `
    -FrontendPorts $FrontEndPort `
    -Probes $HealthProbe `
    -BackendAddressPools $PlatformBackendPool, $ApiBackendPool `
    -BackendHttpSettingsCollection $PoolSettings `
    -Force
```

This, however, ends with:

```
cmdlet New-AzApplicationGateway at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
GatewayIPConfigurations[0]:
```

`$GatewayIPconfig.GetType()` yields

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSApplicationGatewayIPConfiguration      Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSChildResource
```

and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-azapplicationgateway?view=azps-4.8.0) for the cmdlet states that the signature is

```
New-AzApplicationGateway
   ...
   -GatewayIPConfigurations <PSApplicationGatewayIPConfiguration[]>
   ...
```

Is this not the proper way to pass an array argument to a cmdlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a guess, but do you maybe have a stray space or tab after `-Sku $GatewaySku '` ? That might produce exactly the behavior you described. Basically that would be interpreted as:

```
$Gateway = New-AzApplicationGateway `
    -Name $GatewayName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -Location $Location `
    -Sku $GatewaySku
# (the rest of the arguments will be missing)
```

It's a common pitfall when using the backtick that way. It is often recommended not to do it. It's because the backtick is not a continuation but an *escape* character, so *anything* after it will be escaped. When using it as you do, it's the line-break that is escaped, so you can put the arguments on separate lines, but if there's other whitespace in-between, this will break.

Best practice is to write everything in one line, or if there are too many arguments to keep it readable, you can use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7):

```bsh
$params = @{
    Name = $GatewayName
    ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroupName
    Location = $Location
    Sku = $GatewaySku
    GatewayIPConfigurations = $GatewayIPconfig
    FrontendIPConfigurations = $FrontendIpConfig
    FrontendPorts = $FrontEndPort
    Probes = $HealthProbe
    BackendAddressPools = $PlatformBackendPool, $ApiBackendPool
    BackendHttpSettingsCollection = $PoolSettings
    Force = $true
}
$Gateway = New-AzApplicationGateway @params
```

Comment: Thank you @marsze, that was it! I was going crazy already. No more backticks from now on :)